# Not Showing nested JSONn Data from Custom API in FlatList in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I tried several times to fetch data, but it is not showing anything in the app.
Here is the code base for the fetching API data.
It is console logging.

1. the data is console logging in the metro
2. but while trying to render in the flat List it is not showing anything, instead a blank page is displayed.
3. the data is a nested objects.

   ```
   import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
   import {FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View} from 'react-native';

   export default FoodProductsApi = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   const getFoodApi = () => {
   fetch(
     'url',
     {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         countryName: 'India',
         deliveryPincode: '5600100',
         categoryType: 'Food',
       }),
     },
   )
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
       setData(json.foodProducts);
       console.log(json.foodProducts.categories);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
     });
   };

   useEffect(() => {
   getFoodApi();
   }, []);

   const keyExtractor = () => item => item.id;
   return (
   <SafeAreaView>
     <Text>Name</Text>
     <FlatList
       data={data.foodProducts}
       keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
       renderItem={index => (
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
           {index.data.foodProducts.map((i, v) => {
             <Text>{i.categoryName}</Text>;
           })}
         </View>
       )}
     />
   </SafeAreaView>
   );
   };
   ```

This is the JSON data

```
{
"responseCode": "200",
"responseMessage": "Successfull",
"foodProducts": {
    "hubId": "610299e303be56ca3924971e",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "61028aff294f460012c9101e",
            "categoryName": "Kalyani Biryani",
            "rankOrder": 6,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createDate": "2021-07-29T11:03:27.345+0000",
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedDate": "2021-07-29T13:17:55.270+0000",
            "updateBy": "60b12c9e637d050012a7cf6b",
            "zohoCategoryId": "594850000000019627",
            "foodCategoryImage": "",
            "categoryType": "Food",
            "foodProducts": [
                {
                    "id": "6102aa6f03be56ca3924b8f9",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022886",
                    "productName": "Kalyani Chicken Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B035",
                    "mrp": 500,
                    "discountedPrice": 400,
                    "rankOrder": 6,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5006096",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.059+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.059+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Chicken",
                    "spiceLevel": "2",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "58.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b900",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022946",
                    "productName": "Kalyani Egg Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B037",
                    "mrp": 300,
                    "discountedPrice": 290,
                    "rankOrder": 6,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5006097",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.348+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.348+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Egg",
                    "spiceLevel": "3",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "56.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b907",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022915",
                    "productName": "Kalyani Mutton Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B036",
                    "mrp": 200,
                    "discountedPrice": 160,
                    "rankOrder": 6,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5006096",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.652+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.652+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Mutton",
                    "spiceLevel": "2",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "52.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b910",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022977",
                    "productName": "Kalyani Paneer Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Veg",
                    "sku": "B038",
                    "mrp": 200,
                    "discountedPrice": 160,
                    "rankOrder": 12,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5006978",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.938+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.938+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": null,
                    "spiceLevel": "1",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "51.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa7603be56ca3924b992",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022762",
                    "productName": "Thalassery  Chicken Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B031",
                    "mrp": 400,
                    "discountedPrice": 320,
                    "rankOrder": 17,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5006990",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:18.173+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:18.173+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Chicken",
                    "spiceLevel": "2",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "128.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "61028aa8294f460012c9101b",
            "categoryName": "Bombay Biryani",
            "rankOrder": 23,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createDate": "2021-07-29T11:02:00.541+0000",
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedDate": "2021-07-29T13:18:27.081+0000",
            "updateBy": "60b12c9e637d050012a7cf6b",
            "zohoCategoryId": "594850000000019605",
            "foodCategoryImage": "",
            "categoryType": "Food",
            "foodProducts": [
                {
                    "id": "6102aa6803be56ca3924b846",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022576",
                    "productName": "Bombay Paneer Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Veg",
                    "sku": "B024",
                    "mrp": 400,
                    "discountedPrice": 360,
                    "rankOrder": 10,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "50090994",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:03.459+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:03.459+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": null,
                    "spiceLevel": "3",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "130.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa6703be56ca3924b832",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022607",
                    "productName": "Bomaby Fish Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B025",
                    "mrp": 250,
                    "discountedPrice": 170,
                    "rankOrder": 11,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "50090995",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.305+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.305+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Sea Food",
                    "spiceLevel": "2",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "145.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "6102aa6803be56ca3924b83d",
                    "zohoItemId": "594850000000022638",
                    "productName": "Bombay Egg Biryani",
                    "productImage": null,
                    "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
                    "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
                    "sku": "B026",
                    "mrp": 240,
                    "discountedPrice": 210,
                    "rankOrder": 16,
                    "description": null,
                    "hsnCode": "5009099",
                    "gstPercentageInter": "12",
                    "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.885+0000",
                    "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.885+0000",
                    "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
                    "nonVegType": "Egg",
                    "spiceLevel": "3",
                    "categoryType": "Food",
                    "availableStock": "-141.000000",
                    "isFavorite": null,
                    "hubId": null
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: [section list](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) might be more suitable for your use case.

Comment: ok I'll try it ..

Comment: it's not working can you pls write the sample code for the data above ...

Answer (score 1):

Flatlist will loop only array of object . in your code you have tried to loop objects (data.foodProducts).

Replace `data={data.foodProducts}` to `data={data.foodproducts.categories}`. Now it will loop, because its an array of objects.

Array of objects will be similar to this `[{name:"React",age:5}]`. This will be looped by flatlist

Objects will be similar to this `{name:"react",age:5}`. This will not looped by flatlist.

You can check whether data is an array or object using `console.log(typeof data.foodproducts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Solves your Problem,

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
FlatList
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
getFoodApi();
}, []);

function getFoodApi()
{
  setData({
    "foodProducts": {
      "hubId": "610299e303be56ca3924971e",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "61028aff294f460012c9101e",
          "categoryName": "Kalyani Biryani",
          "rankOrder": 6,
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "createDate": "2021-07-29T11:03:27.345+0000",
          "createdBy": null,
          "updatedDate": "2021-07-29T13:17:55.270+0000",
          "updateBy": "60b12c9e637d050012a7cf6b",
          "zohoCategoryId": "594850000000019627",
          "foodCategoryImage": "",
          "categoryType": "Food",
          "foodProducts": [
            {
              "id": "6102aa6f03be56ca3924b8f9",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022886",
              "productName": "Kalyani Chicken Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B035",
              "mrp": 500,
              "discountedPrice": 400,
              "rankOrder": 6,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5006096",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.059+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.059+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Chicken",
              "spiceLevel": "2",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "58.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            
            {
              "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b900",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022946",
              "productName": "Kalyani Egg Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B037",
              "mrp": 300,
              "discountedPrice": 290,
              "rankOrder": 6,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5006097",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.348+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.348+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Egg",
              "spiceLevel": "3",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "56.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b907",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022915",
              "productName": "Kalyani Mutton Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B036",
              "mrp": 200,
              "discountedPrice": 160,
              "rankOrder": 6,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5006096",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.652+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.652+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Mutton",
              "spiceLevel": "2",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "52.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "6102aa7003be56ca3924b910",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022977",
              "productName": "Kalyani Paneer Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Veg",
              "sku": "B038",
              "mrp": 200,
              "discountedPrice": 160,
              "rankOrder": 12,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5006978",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.938+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:11.938+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": null,
              "spiceLevel": "1",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "51.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "6102aa7603be56ca3924b992",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022762",
              "productName": "Thalassery  Chicken Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019627",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B031",
              "mrp": 400,
              "discountedPrice": 320,
              "rankOrder": 17,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5006990",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:18.173+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:18.173+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Chicken",
              "spiceLevel": "2",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "128.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            }
          ]//food products[0]
        }, //categories[0]
        {
          "id": "61028aa8294f460012c9101b",
          "categoryName": "Bombay Biryani",
          "rankOrder": 23,
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "createDate": "2021-07-29T11:02:00.541+0000",
          "createdBy": null,
          "updatedDate": "2021-07-29T13:18:27.081+0000",
          "updateBy": "60b12c9e637d050012a7cf6b",
          "zohoCategoryId": "594850000000019605",
          "foodCategoryImage": "",
          "categoryType": "Food",
          "foodProducts": [
            {
              "id": "6102aa6803be56ca3924b846",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022576",
              "productName": "Bombay Paneer Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Veg",
              "sku": "B024",
              "mrp": 400,
              "discountedPrice": 360,
              "rankOrder": 10,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "50090994",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:03.459+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:03.459+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": null,
              "spiceLevel": "3",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "130.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "6102aa6703be56ca3924b832",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022607",
              "productName": "Bomaby Fish Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B025",
              "mrp": 250,
              "discountedPrice": 170,
              "rankOrder": 11,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "50090995",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.305+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.305+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Sea Food",
              "spiceLevel": "2",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "145.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "6102aa6803be56ca3924b83d",
              "zohoItemId": "594850000000022638",
              "productName": "Bombay Egg Biryani",
              "productImage": null,
              "categoryId": "594850000000019605",
              "vegNonVegFlag": "Non Veg",
              "sku": "B026",
              "mrp": 240,
              "discountedPrice": 210,
              "rankOrder": 16,
              "description": null,
              "hsnCode": "5009099",
              "gstPercentageInter": "12",
              "gstPercentageIntra": "12",
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "createdDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.885+0000",
              "createdBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "updatedDate": "2021-08-11T07:51:02.885+0000",
              "updatedBy": "Zoho Sync Script",
              "nonVegType": "Egg",
              "spiceLevel": "3",
              "categoryType": "Food",
              "availableStock": "-141.000000",
              "isFavorite": null,
              "hubId": null
            }
          
          ]
        }
      ]//categories
          }//foodApi
        })
}

return (
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
  <Text>Name</Text>
    <FlatList
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={data.foodProducts.categories}
      keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text> categoreyname  {item.categoryName}</Text>
            {item.foodProducts.map(ele => {
              return (
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}> productName { ele.productName}</Text>
              )
            })}
        </View>
        )
      }}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 

});

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.